# Conflict between Bootstrap and other font icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome-4

I am using bootstrap3 in my project. Now i want to use some font-icons besides with it's core icons.
First I tried Font Awesome4, but it seems that there is some problem and icons are displaying like squares. also I tried FlatUI icons and the same problem appeared..

Does anyone have this trouble? How can I resolve it?

---

EDIT

for example for fontawesome I put the link below in my header

`<link href="{{ asset('css/font-icon/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />`

I have also tried using cdn

`<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">`

I checked it with firebug, the fonts are loaded but it appears like some squares :|
[image: the square]

[image: firebug inspection]

Comment: hmmm, its happens if u dont have font included or he just missing. Do you have your font in the right folder?

Comment: Can you show an example of your code where you have added the font awesome files.

Comment: Please provide your font include and your HTML markup

Comment: @Nividim, thanks for your comment, I've updated the question with additional information.

Comment: @BenEgan1991,  thanks for your comment, I've updated the question with additional information.

Comment: `src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');` Do you have that `.eot` file in folder `/fonts`?

Comment: @Nividim, Yes! I've extracted the given folder from fontawesome and not changed.
And as I said, it has the problem with other font icons too, i thought that maybe the problem is woth bootstrap.. maybe I should change some thing in it..

Comment: @Nividim, thanks for you answer :)
I resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution, maybe dirty one..

I added this lines to my css:

```
[class*="fa-"]{
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

and also these ones to my .htaccess

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```